# Simple input validation and adding values to table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add product info from inputs to table by using jQuery library. I am trying for quite some time now, but I don't get anywhere. First I need to enter data to inputs, select appropriate radio button and than validate input fields. If there are no errors, product info should be added to table. I tried with the following code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KS3sM/7/)

Nothing works as intended tho. What am I doing wrong?

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//Global variables
var productName = "";
var price = 0;
var onStack = "N/A";

$("body > form").submit(function () {
    //Check if any of requested inputs is empty
    if ($("#name").val().length == 0) {
        //Missing name alert
        $("#errors").val('Missing product name');
        break;
    } else if ($("#price").val() == 0) {
        //Missing price alert
        $("#errors").val('Missing price');
        break;
    }

    //Get values from text inputs
    productName = $("#name").val();
    price = $("#price").val();

    //Check radio buttons and assign values
    if ($('input[value = "true"]'.is(':checked')) {
        onStack = "Product available";
    } else if ('input[value = "false"]'.is(':checked') {
        onStack = "Not available";
    }

    //Add values to table
    $("table tr:last").after("<tr><td>$productName</td><td>$price</td><td>$onStack</td></tr>");
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>

<body>
    <form method="" action="">
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Product name" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="price" placeholder="Price" />
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="stack" value="true">Product available
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="stack" value="false">Product not available
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <div id="errors"></div>
    <br />
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Product name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Stack</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="sumOnStack">Sum of available products</div>
    <div id="SumNotOnStack">Sum of unavailable products</div>
    <input type="button" id="resetForm" value="Reset form" />
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can definitely display HTML here, and that would be better than asking us to go to another site to see your question. HTML should be formatted as code, just as has been done with your JS.

Comment: There is a typo in the spelling of "length".

Comment: you did not included jQuery libraries. check it once

Comment: Edited my question. Everything is now in english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Global variables
    var productName = "";
    var price = 0;
    var onStack = "N/A";

    $("body > form").submit(function ( e) {
        //Check if any of requested inputs is empty
         $("#errors").html('');
        if ($("#name").val().length == 0) {
            //Missing name alert
            $("#errors").html('Missing product name');
            return false;

        } else if ($("#price").val() == 0) {
            //Missing price alert
            $("#errors").html('Missing price');
            return false;
        } else if($('input[name="stack"]:checked').length == 0) {
            $("#errors").html('Missing product availibility');
            return false;

        }

        //Get values from text inputs
        productName = $("#name").val();
        price = $("#price").val();
        var stack = $('input[name="stack"]:checked');
        console.log( $(stack).val() );
        //Check radio buttons and assign values
        if ($(stack).val() == 'true') {
            onStack = "Product available";
        } else {
            onStack = "Not available";
        }

        //Add values to table
        $("table tr:last").after("<tr><td>"+productName+"</td><td>"+ price +"</td><td>"+ onStack +"</td></tr>");
        return false;
        });
    });
```

Please try this. Hope above code will help u.

Comment: Tried it. Nothing changed.

Comment: Tried it. Now i get an error "{"error": "Please use POST request"}" when clicking submit button on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KS3sM/16/

Comment: Nevermind above comment, it is working now. Thank you for your help.